# Faster approach to finding distance between coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, haversine

I have a list of places and I need to find the distance between each of those. Can anyone suggest a faster method? There are about 10k unique places, the method I'm using creates a `10k X 10k` matrix and I'm running out of memory. I'm using 15GB RAM.

```
    test_df

   Latitude  Longitude  site
    0   32.3    -94.1   1
    1   35.2    -93.1   2
    2   33.1    -83.4   3
    3   33.2    -94.5   4
test_df = test_df[['site', 'Longitude', 'Latitude']]    
test_df['coord'] = list(zip(test_df['Longitude'], test_df['Latitude']))
from haversine import haversine
for _,row in test_df.iterrows():
    test_df[row.coord]=round(test_df['coord'].apply(lambda x:haversine(row.coord,x, unit='mi')),2)
df = test_df.rename(columns=dict(zip(test_df['coord'], test_df['Facility'])))
df.drop('coord', axis=1, inplace=True)
new_df = pd.melt(df, id_vars='Facility', value_vars=df.columns[1:])
new_df.rename(columns={'variable':'Place', 'value':'dist_in_mi'}, inplace=True)
new_df


 site Place dist_in_mi
0   1   1   0.00
1   2   1   70.21
2   3   1   739.28
3   4   1   28.03
4   1   2   70.21
5   2   2   0.00
6   3   2   670.11
7   4   2   97.15
8   1   3   739.28
9   2   3   670.11
10  3   3   0.00
11  4   3   766.94
12  1   4   28.03
13  2   4   97.15
14  3   4   766.94
15  4   4   0.00
```

Comment: Could we have the dataframe in copy-pastable form (e.g. hosted on github)?

Comment: you are asking for a faster method but then you say that the problem is that you run out of memory

Comment: you're right, I need a faster method since the way I used it, isn't optimized - I tried with a dummy set which I shared here, which works

Comment: for a faster method i recommend to use multiprocessing and to not calculate the distance from the same places 2 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to resolve your memory problem you need to use datatypes that use less memory.
In this case since the maximum distance between two points on the planet Earth is less than `20005Km` you can use `uint16` to store the value (if a 1Km resolution is enough for you)

Since i hadn't any data to work with i generated some data with the following code:

```
import random

import numpy as np
from haversine import haversine

def getNFacilities(n):
    """ returns n random pairs of coordinates in the range [-90, +90]"""
    for i in range(n):
        yield random.random()*180 - 90, random.random()*180 - 90

facilities = list(getNFacilities(10000))
```

Then i resolved the memory problem in two different ways:

1- By storing the distance data in `uint16` numbers

```
def calculateDistance(start, end):
    mirror = start is end # if the matrix is mirrored the values are calculated just one time instead of two
    out = np.zeros((len(start), len(end)), dtype = np.uint16) # might be better to use empty?
    for i, coords1 in enumerate(start[mirror:], mirror):
        for j, coords2 in enumerate(end[:mirror and i or None]):
            out[i, j] = int(haversine(coords1, coords2))
    return out
```

After calculating the distance the memory used by the array was about 200MB:

```
In [133]: l = calculateDistance(facilities, facilities)

In [134]: sys.getsizeof(l)
Out[134]: 200000112
```

2- Or in alternative you can just use a generator:

```
def calculateDistance(start, end):
    mirror = start is end # if the matrix is mirrored the values are calculated just one time
    for i, coords1 in enumerate(start[mirror:], mirror):
        for j, coords2 in enumerate(end[:mirror and i or None]):
            yield [i, j, haversine(coords1, coords2)]
```

Comment: Using the generator approach, when i use a for..loop to read to a dataframe, it runs out of memory again, any suggestion?

Comment: generators are awesome for "on the fly" calculations, eg. finding the mean distance between the facilities, but if you need to store the value in ram the first method might be better

Comment: or you can check some methods to work with large datasets here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html#use-chunking